# Can't able to add Expandable ListView to a Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

[this is the fragment where i want to add the expandable list view the grey colored space below the image of news and update (Click to Open Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bHNP.png)

Can't able to add Expandable ListView to a Fragment getting an error.

i have a navigation drawer to navigate through news and update fragment in which i want an expandable listview but i can't able to add it i don't know how to solve this problem

fragment_news_update.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.aakash.myapp.news_update"
android:background="#d3d3d3">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:background="@drawable/news_update_top" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:id="@+id/expListView"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />
```

news_update.java

```
package com.example.aakash.myapp;

 public class news_update extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_update, container, false);
}


public news_update() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

{

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.expListView);

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
    listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
    listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
    top250.add("The Godfather");
    top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
    top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
    top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
    top250.add("The Dark Knight");
    top250.add("12 Angry Men");

    List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
    nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
    nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
    nowShowing.add("Turbo");
    nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
    nowShowing.add("Red 2");
    nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

    List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
    comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
    comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
    comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
    comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
    comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
}
```

}

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
package info.androidhive.expandablelistview;


  public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.aakash.myapp;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {

NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar=null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    //set an initial fragment
    home fragment = new home();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();




     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Not Available Right Now !!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

        home fragment = new home();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


        // Handle the camera action
    }
    if (id == R.id.nav_news_updates) {

        news_update fragment = new news_update();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_admission) {

        Gallery_Fragment fragment = new Gallery_Fragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_results) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_l_o_h) {

    }  else if (id == R.id.nav_contact_us) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.aakash.myapp" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>
```

[Click to open Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYmk4.png)

error_log

```
06-03 22:20:05.587 3547-3547/com.example.aakash.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.example.aakash.myapp, PID: 3547
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at com.example.aakash.myapp.news_update.<init>(news_update.java:46)
                                                                        at com.example.aakash.myapp.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:111)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:151)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
                                                                        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:318)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: show your manifest. i think you forget to remove activity from that

Comment: added the AndroidManifest.xml coding Please Check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fragment` doesn't have `setContentView()` method and you can not use `findViewById()` method directly in `Fragment`. For you reference read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html). Instead of `setContentView()`, here you have to inflate the resource file as mentioned in link and collect inflated ViewGroup into you local ViewGroup. Once you have that inflated ViewGroup, you can find any view inside that particular ViewGroup.

First do all these, read the link and try to run the application. Your problem will get resolved

Comment: I edit the 'news_update.java' please check..
myapp crashes when i click the news update from navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

why are you extending your news_update to `FragmentActivity`. just extends with Fragment. FragmentActivity is not a fragment it a sub class of Activity so that you are getting error `news_update cannot be converted to Fragment`

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 public class news_update extends Fragment{}
```

Comment: Done! But setcontentview findviewbyid and setcontextfunction are not working then i manage to sort them out then the issue is when i am clicking for news & update on navigation drawer the app crashes

Comment: I edit the 'news_update.java' please check.. myapp crashes when i click the news update from navigation drawer

HELP PLEASE

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/hYmk4.png chek out the screenshot here !